# What difference is between a Coons B-spline and a  Bezier Spline?

Tags: math, graphics, bezier, spline, bspline

1. What is the difference between a Coons B-Spline and a Bezier Spline?
2. Should I say "Bezier Spline" or "Bezier B-spline"? What is the right term?

I've read some articles about it, but they usually discuss both of these types of spline together, so I have it a little messed up and don't know what info belongs to what type of curve.